# disable form field on checkbox select wih jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need be able to disable form element and add a class "disabled" in all TDs with class="myToggle". Not sure if I'm doing it right:

```
$("#myCheck").click(function() {
  $(".myToggle").addClass("disabled").attr("disabled", true);
});

<td><checkbox id="myCheck"> My checkbox</td>
<td class="myToggle"> My label</td>
<td class="myToggle">
    <select>
       <option>option
    </select>
</td>
```

Can I combine like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#myCheck").click(function() {
  $(".myToggle").find("input, select, textarea")
    .addClass("disabled")
    .attr("disabled", true);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe jQuery has it's [own toggle function](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) for elements to show/hide them.

```
$('.target').toggle();
```

But what you wrote should work too, since you are trying to operate on a class, and many element can share the same class name at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Your Problem is not clear still u may try this and check if i has got some thing to help?

http://jsfiddle.net/CStTZ/5/